# temp files remain in GCS after a Dataflow job "succeeded"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My team runs several hourly/daily Dataflow jobs, which mostly read from and write to GCS (that said, we have dozens of recurring Dataflow jobs scheduled to run within a day).
Some jobs read the data from GCS which is produced by previous jobs.
Roughly once or twice in a week, we face the following issue:

- Job A successfully runs, and writes its output to GCS at gs://A/output/.
- (the main issue which takes places between Job A and Job B we identified is described in the next paragraph).
- Job B reads from gs://A/output to process some data, but throws an exception because either a temp file was removed while the job was running or due to temp files the keys in the data are no longer unique (e.g., if Job B creates a MapView of the data above, this occurs).

So the reason, as far as we were able to debug is the following:

- By the time Job A finishes (according to its pipeline status, e.g.), all 'temp' files under gs://A/output/ should have been renamed to the file name(s) specified by the job.
- Yet some of these temp files are lingering around for a few minutes after Job A finishes -- sometimes, we even see those temp files a few hours after the completion of Job A, so we often have to remove them manually.
- For instance, we only see one or two temp files lingering around out of ~7,500 files in the directory, and they often go away within an hour, but sometimes they stay for a few hours.

We are wondering about the following:

- Is our understanding correct that all "temp" files in GCS output directory should be renamed before Job A "finishes" (e.g., on the monitoring UI it says it succeeded, and it has stopped worker pool, etc.)? In other words, completion of a job is an indicator that the temp files are gone?

  - If yes, is it a bug that we see temp files much after the job is completed?
  - If no, how can we (the user) know that the job is "really" completed in the sense that its output directory does not contain temp files? (Should we check it with our own file pattern matching script or something like that?)

I did some search with GCS and Dataflow as keywords, but found nothing close to the issue we are having -- but I might have missed something, so any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. This is a bug in TextIO.Write, caused by the fact that, when deleting temporary files, it suffers from [GCS eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency), and fails to find and delete all of them.

Ffortunately, it still looks at all the correct files when copying temporary files to their final location, so there is no data loss.

We will look into providing a fix.

Note that again due to GCS eventual consistency, job B can also *fail to read* some outputs produced by A - this will stay true even with the potential fix, and Dataflow has no easy way of addressing this right now. However, the chances of this decrease as you increase the interval between finishing A and starting B.

I would recommend, if possible, to join A and B into a single pipeline, representing this data as an intermediate `PCollection`. If you need to have this data materialized as text on GCS for other purposes (e.g. manual inspection, serving, processing by a different tool, etc.), you can still also do that from this joint pipeline, just do not use GCS for passing data between one pipeline and another.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! Unfortunately, those files are still available in that Job B actually reads those temp files (in addition to the regular files), and complains that there are "duplicates" (which should not happen because Job A outputs data with unique keys). Upon seeing such error messages, one of our engineers would go and check for temp files, and indeed there they are, delete them manually via gsutil command (which does not fail, indicating that those files are existent), and re-run Job B (which then runs without errors).
So the issue we are facing seems a bit different.

Comment: OK, I read your question some more, and I think we're talking about different things. What do you mean by "temp files"? Can you give me an example Dataflow job ID of jobs A, B, and an example path to a "lingering" file, and describe what was supposed to happen to the file and what actually happened?

Comment: [post 1-of-2 due to char limit]
 
Job A: 2016-10-01_20_56_19-5249395331261744641

This job wrote to gs://dataflow-appprofile/2016-10-01/appprofile-daily-20161001-aaaaa-of-bbbbb. 
Note that this job terminated at Oct 1, 2016, 9:47:55 PM (pacific time).

Job B: 2016-10-01_21_52_18-1981569070131419993
When Job B started at 9:52pm, one of the temp files (gs://dataflow-appprofile/2016-10-01/appprofile-daily-20161001-temp-3d1e4c54-901d-4db3-ac1d-8b47a6d8a5c8) was still existent, and Job B failed (due to duplicate keys).

Comment: [post 2-of-2] 
Some time later, we learned that Job B failed, so we re-ran Job B (without knowing about the temp file at this point) at 10:06pm (job ID 2016-10-01_22_06_19-855456315573777776), ant it failed for the same reason. 

Around 10:15-10:20pm (so at least 30 minutes after Job A terminated),
we manually removed the temp file (via "gsutil rm gs://dataflow-appprofile/2016-10-01/appprofile-daily-20161001-temp-3d1e4c54-901d-4db3-ac1d-8b47a6d8a5c8"), and re-ran Job B for the third time (Job ID 2016-10-01_22_29_23-12660764751435178410), which finally succeeded.

Comment: [update] This happened once again just now. 
Job A: 2016-10-03_19_50_18-12148037691794303211 (terminated at 8:36:59pm)
This generated 20 files and 4 temp files were lingering until just now (I made a screenshot to retain their names if you need), which I removed. 
Job B failed: 2016-10-03_20_55_19-948013433821887252 (started at 8:55:19pm, about 20 minutes after job A completed).

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Yes, sorry for the trouble, this looks like a bug in TextIO.Write, caused by the fact that, when deleting temporary files, it suffers from the same issue of GCS eventual consistency, and fails to find and delete all of them (fortunately, it still looks at all the correct files when *copying* temporary files to their final location, so there is no data loss). We will look into providing a fix.

Comment: You can follow the fix in https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/pull/1050 which will afterwards be backported into the Dataflow SDK.

Comment: Backport into Dataflow SDK happening in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/pull/482

Comment: Dataflow SDK backport has been merged. The issue should be a lot less severe now, if you run your jobs against an artifact of the SDK built from github.